# While loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random

I have the following JavaScript to get a random image from a list of available images:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var image = new Array();
var link  = new Array();

image[0] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus01_small.png';
image[1] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus02_small.png';
image[2] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus03_small.png';
image[3] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus04_small.png';
image[4] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus05_small.png';
image[5] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus06_small.png';
image[6] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus07_small.png';
image[7] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus08_small.png';
image[8] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus09_small.png';
image[9] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus10_small.png';
image[10] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus11_small.png';
image[11] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus12_small.png';
image[12] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus13_small.png';
image[13] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus14_small.png';
image[14] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus15_small.png';
image[15] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus16_small.png';
image[16] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus17_small.png';
image[17] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus18_small.png';
image[18] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus19_small.png';
image[19] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus20_small.png';
image[20] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus21_small.png';
image[21] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus22_small.png';
image[22] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus23_small.png';
image[23] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus24_small.png';
image[24] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus26_small.png';
image[25] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus27_small.png';
image[26] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus28_small.png';
image[27] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus29_small.png';

link[1] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/index.php?page=bildergalerie';

var num = Math.random();
var ran = Math.floor((image.length - 1) * num) + 1;

document.write('<a href="' + link[1] + '" mce_href="' + link[1] + '"><img src="' + image[ran] + '" mce_src="' + image[ran] + '" border="0" + width="200" /></a>');
// ]]></script>
```

Now I'd like to change the code so that there are three random images. I was able to do it, by just using this code three times. Unfortunately, then there is the possibility that the same images is randomly choosen multiple times. So how can I avoid that the same image is chosen multiple times? I think I have to maintain a list of selected images and then chose a new image randomly until a image that is not in the list is chosen. But how do I do this?

Comment: I suggest you dont manually define every link if their bases are the same. Use a function that adds it in. Faster loading.

Comment: yes I'd like to use all images in http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery but I don't know yet how to do it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var image = [];
var link  = [];

image[0] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus01_small.png';
image[1] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus02_small.png';
image[2] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus03_small.png';
image[3] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus04_small.png';
image[4] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus05_small.png';
image[5] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus06_small.png';
image[6] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus07_small.png';
image[7] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus08_small.png';
image[8] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus09_small.png';
image[9] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus10_small.png';
image[10] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus11_small.png';
image[11] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus12_small.png';
image[12] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus13_small.png';
image[13] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus14_small.png';
image[14] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus15_small.png';
image[15] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus16_small.png';
image[16] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus17_small.png';
image[17] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus18_small.png';
image[18] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus19_small.png';
image[19] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus20_small.png';
image[20] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus21_small.png';
image[21] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus22_small.png';
image[22] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus23_small.png';
image[23] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus24_small.png';
image[24] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus26_small.png';
image[25] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus27_small.png';
image[26] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus28_small.png';
image[27] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus29_small.png';

link[1] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/index.php?page=bildergalerie';
function pickImage(){
   var pick = Math.floor(Math.random()*image.length);
   var img = image.splice(pick, 1);

   document.write('<a href="' + link[1] + '" mce_href="' + link[1] + '"><img src="' + img + '" mce_src="' + img + '" border="0" + width="200" /></a>');
}

pickImage();
pickImage();
//add as much pickImage(); as you want
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that also result in duplicate images?

Comment: Nope, unless you're defining image again.
Note that if we're out of images, nothing will be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to shuffle the array with any server side technique. If you get the images from a data base you can use it's randomizing or if you use PHP you can use [shuffle()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php). Then you just have to take the first three images.

**EDIT**: As you seems to use PHP on that page, try the following:

```
$images = array('01','02','03','04','05', ... ): // the numbers of the images
shuffle($images):

for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
    echo "image[".$i."] = 'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus".$images[$i]."_small.png';
}
```

Insert that into the script tag to only print out three lines of javascript for the array.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to remove the picked images from the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var index = Math.floor(image.length * Math.random());
  var picked = image.splice(index, 1)[0];
  document.write(
    '<a href="' + link[1] + '" mce_href="' + link[1] + '">' +
    '<img src="' + picked + '" mce_src="' + picked + '" border="0" + width="200" />' +
    '</a>'
  );
}
```

Note that I corrected the calculation of the random index. The orignal never picked the first item in the array.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with [Guffa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565306/while-loop-in-javascript/3565422#3565422). And I would create the array like this:

```
var images = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 28 ; i++){
    images[i] =
     'http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/schwalbenhaus/schwalbenhaus' 
       + ( i < 10 ? '0' : '')
       + '_small.png';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. As far as I can see you parse the whole directory to get the images? However this works for this case, but I'd like to extend my script so that all images in the directory http://www.ovlu.li/ornitholog/cms/images/gallery/ and below are used.

Comment: you can't parse a directory in javascript. I was relying on the obvious naming convention. If you have one, use it. Otherwise you are going to have to either create the array on the server (by PHP or other) or manually in your html code.